# Beamer - Modify frame environment with frame title

Tags: beamer, frame-title

To include some heading (just above the content) in a beamer frame, I am using this code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldframe\frame
\def\frame{\@ifnextchar[\frame@i \frame@ii}
\def\frame@i[#1]{\oldframe[#1] Heading}
\def\frame@ii{\oldframe Heading}
\makeatother
```

It works well along with all options, but the frame title appears at an odd location (along with the content, instead of the normal top position). Does anybody know how to fix it?

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\oldframe\frame
\def\frame{\@ifnextchar[\frame@i \frame@ii}
\def\frame@i[#1]{\oldframe[#1] Heading}
\def\frame@ii{\oldframe Heading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
The title does not appear as expected
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This might cause trouble for fragile frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend the redefinition of the frame environment. This can cause problems, especially with fragile content.

If you really must do it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{myframe}[1]
    {\begin{frame}[environment=myframe]
        \frametitle{#1}
        Heading\par
        }
    {\end{frame}}


\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}{Title}
The title does not appear as expected
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

(see beamer user guide, section 8.1, for more information)